# Java swing components layout position changes after restoring a minimized window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I'm developing a Flight Information Display(FIDs) Application that displays information with JLabels. I have different JPanels that contains different labels.

My issue is that when I launch the window, it displays properly with each components maintaining its desired layout position but the label position changes (clusters at the center) when you try to restore the window after minimizing it. Thereby clustering all the labels together. Please I really need to resolve this.

Below is my code snippet:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Departure extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    final private JPanel container = new JPanel();
    final private JPanel secPanel;
    final private JPanel imgPanel;
    final private JLabel logo;
    final private JLabel lagosLbl;
    final private JLabel londonLbl;
    final private JLabel newYorkLbl;
    final private JLabel lagosTime;
    final private JLabel londonTime;
    final private JLabel newYorkTime;
    final private JLabel departureLbl;
    final private JLabel airlineHd;
    final private JLabel flightHd;
    final private JLabel destHd;
    final private JLabel schedHd;
    final private JLabel gateHd;
    final private JLabel statusHd;
    final private JLabel footer;
    private JLabel footerLeft, footerMid, footerRight;


    private String todayDate, timeLocale, timeLondon, timeNewYork;

    Dimension sizeMain, sizeHeading, sizeBody, sizeLogo, sizeSec, screenSize;
    Insets insetsMain, insetsHeading, insetsBody, insetsLogo, insetsSec;

    public Departure(){

        super("DEPARTURES");

        screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);      
        this.setVisible(true);



        container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenSize.width, 
        screenSize.height));
        container.setBackground(new Color(53,86,163));
        this.getContentPane().add(container);

        Insets insets = this.getInsets();
        Dimension size = container.getPreferredSize();
        container.setBounds(0 + insets.left, 0 + insets.top,
        size.width + 5, size.height + 5);
        container.setLayout(null);


        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("headerDe.jpg"));
        logo = new JLabel();
        logo.setIcon(new 
        ImageIcon(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(screenSize.width, 200,
        java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        logo.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
        container.add(logo);

        insetsMain = container.getInsets();
        sizeMain = logo.getPreferredSize();
        logo.setBounds(0 + insetsMain.left, 0 + insetsMain.top,
        sizeMain.width + 5, sizeMain.height + 5);


        lagosLbl = new JLabel("LAGOS:");
        lagosLbl.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 40));
        lagosLbl.setForeground(new Color(0,0,140));
        logo.add(lagosLbl);

        insetsLogo = logo.getInsets();
        sizeLogo = lagosLbl.getPreferredSize();
        lagosLbl.setBounds(1550 + insetsLogo.left, 5 + insetsLogo.top,
        sizeLogo.width + 5, sizeLogo.height + 5);

        timeLocale = myTimeLocale();
        lagosTime = new JLabel(timeLocale);
        lagosTime.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 45));
        lagosTime.setForeground(new Color(0,0,140));
        logo.add(lagosTime);

        sizeLogo = lagosTime.getPreferredSize();
        lagosTime.setBounds(1750 + insetsLogo.left, 2 + insetsLogo.top,
        sizeLogo.width + 5, sizeLogo.height + 5);


        londonLbl = new JLabel("LONDON:");
        londonLbl.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 40));
        londonLbl.setForeground(new Color(0,0,140));
        logo.add(londonLbl);

        sizeLogo = londonLbl.getPreferredSize();
        londonLbl.setBounds(1515 + insetsLogo.left, 65 + insetsLogo.top,
        sizeLogo.width + 5, sizeLogo.height + 5);

        timeLondon = myTimeLondon();
        londonTime = new JLabel(timeLondon);
        londonTime.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 45));
        londonTime.setForeground(new Color(0,0,140));
        logo.add(londonTime);

        sizeLogo = londonTime.getPreferredSize();
        londonTime.setBounds(1750 + insetsLogo.left, 62 + insetsLogo.top,
        sizeLogo.width + 5, sizeLogo.height + 5);

        newYorkLbl = new JLabel("NEW YORK:");
        newYorkLbl.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 40));
        newYorkLbl.setForeground(new Color(0,0,140));
        logo.add(newYorkLbl);

        sizeLogo = newYorkLbl.getPreferredSize();
        newYorkLbl.setBounds(1485 + insetsLogo.left, 125 + insetsLogo.top,
        sizeLogo.width + 5, sizeLogo.height + 5);

        timeNewYork = myTimeNewYork();

        newYorkTime = new JLabel(timeNewYork);
        newYorkTime.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 45));
        newYorkTime.setForeground(new Color(0,0,140));
        myTimeNewYork();
        logo.add(newYorkTime);

        sizeLogo = newYorkTime.getPreferredSize();
        newYorkTime.setBounds(1750 + insetsLogo.left, 122 + insetsLogo.top,
        sizeLogo.width + 5, sizeLogo.height + 5);

        departureLbl = new JLabel("DEPARTURES");
        departureLbl.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 100));
        departureLbl.setForeground(new Color(53,86,163));
        logo.add(departureLbl);

        sizeLogo = departureLbl.getPreferredSize();
        departureLbl.setBounds(680 + insetsLogo.left, 50 + insetsLogo.top,
        sizeLogo.width + 5, sizeLogo.height + 5);


        secPanel = new JPanel();
        secPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( screenSize.width, 
        (screenSize.width - 300) ) );
        secPanel.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        container.add(secPanel);

        sizeMain = secPanel.getPreferredSize();
        secPanel.setBounds(0 + insetsMain.left, 200 + insetsMain.top,
        sizeMain.width + 5, sizeMain.height + 5);


        imgPanel = new JPanel();
        imgPanel.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( screenSize.width,45 ) );
        imgPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,140));
        secPanel.add(imgPanel);

        insetsHeading = secPanel.getInsets();
        sizeHeading = imgPanel.getPreferredSize();
        imgPanel.setBounds(0 + insetsHeading.left, 5 + insetsHeading.top,
        sizeHeading.width + 5, sizeHeading.height + 5);


        schedHd = new JLabel("STD");
        schedHd.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 28));
        schedHd.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        imgPanel.add(schedHd);

        insetsHeading = imgPanel.getInsets();
        sizeHeading = schedHd.getPreferredSize();
        schedHd.setBounds(100 + insetsHeading.left, 5 + insetsHeading.top,
        sizeHeading.width + 5, sizeHeading.height + 5);

        airlineHd = new JLabel("AIRLINE");
        airlineHd.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 28));
        airlineHd.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        imgPanel.add(airlineHd);

        sizeHeading = airlineHd.getPreferredSize();
        airlineHd.setBounds(350 + insetsHeading.left, 5 + insetsHeading.top,
        sizeHeading.width + 5, sizeHeading.height + 5);

        destHd = new JLabel("DESTINATION");
        destHd.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 28));
        destHd.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        imgPanel.add(destHd);

        sizeHeading = destHd.getPreferredSize();
        destHd.setBounds(650 + insetsHeading.left, 5 + insetsHeading.top,
        sizeHeading.width + 5, sizeHeading.height + 5);

        flightHd = new JLabel("FLIGHT");
        flightHd.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 28));
        flightHd.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        imgPanel.add(flightHd);   

        sizeHeading = flightHd.getPreferredSize();
        flightHd.setBounds(1020 + insetsHeading.left, 5 + insetsHeading.top,
        sizeHeading.width + 5, sizeHeading.height + 5);


        gateHd = new JLabel("GATE");
        gateHd.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 28));
        gateHd.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        imgPanel.add(gateHd);

        sizeHeading = gateHd.getPreferredSize();
        gateHd.setBounds(1280 + insetsHeading.left, 5 + insetsHeading.top,
        sizeHeading.width + 5, sizeHeading.height + 5);

        statusHd = new JLabel("STATUS");
        statusHd.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 28));
        statusHd.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        imgPanel.add(statusHd);

        sizeHeading = statusHd.getPreferredSize();
        statusHd.setBounds(1520 + insetsHeading.left, 5 + insetsHeading.top,
        sizeHeading.width + 5, sizeHeading.height + 5);

        ImageIcon foot = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("footer.jpg"));
        footer = new JLabel();
        footer.setIcon(new 
        ImageIcon(foot.getImage().getScaledInstance(screenSize.width, 70,
        java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        secPanel.add(footer);

        size = footer.getPreferredSize();
        footer.setBounds(0 + insets.left, 760 + insets.top,
        size.width + 5, size.height + 5);

        todayDate = dayOfWeek() + "    "+ myDate();
        footerLeft = new JLabel(todayDate);
        footerLeft.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 30));
        footerLeft.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
        footer.add(footerLeft);

        size = footerLeft.getPreferredSize();
        footerLeft.setBounds(15 + insets.left, 15 + insets.top,
        size.width + 5, size.height + 5);

        footerMid = new JLabel();
        //footerMid.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 70));
        footerMid.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 30));
        footerMid.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
        footer.add(footerMid);

        size = footerMid.getPreferredSize();
        footerMid.setBounds(450 + insets.left, 15 + insets.top,
        size.width + 5, size.height + 5);

        footerRight = new JLabel();
        footerRight.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic",Font.BOLD, 30));
        footerRight.setForeground(new Color(255,255,255));
        footer.add(footerRight);

        size = footerRight.getPreferredSize();
        footerRight.setBounds(1540 + insets.left, 15 + insets.top,
        size.width + 5, size.height + 5);


    }

    public String dayOfWeek(){
        Date now = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); // the 
        day of the week in full
        //SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("E"); // the 
        day of the week abbreviated
        return simpleDateformat.format(now);
    }

    protected static String myDate(){
        Calendar myD = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String date = (d.format(myD.getTime()));

        return date;
    }

    public static void main(String args []){
        Departure departure = new Departure();
    }
}
```

[image: When the application is lauched]

[image: After restoring a minimized window]

Comment: 1) `container.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). ..

Comment: .. 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who responded to my question. I later find out that I didn't explicitly define the layout for each of the container(Panels) I declared before adding some contents (Labels) to them, thus the dimension tends to scatter when I restore the window. Though this may be cumbersome but I do enjoy having absolute control over the positioning of each of the item in the window. Thanks once again

Below is an example of how I resolved it;

```
//After initializing the imgPanel

imgPanel.setLayout(null); //explicitly declare the imgPanel layout to null

JLabel lbl = new JLabel("STD");
imgPanel.add(lbl)

Insets imgPanelInsets = imgPanel.getInsets(); //define the components insets
Dimension sizeImg = lbl.getPreferredSize(); //define the components dimension
lbl.setBounds(100 + imgPanelInsets.left, 5 + imgPanelInsets.top,
             sizeImg.width + 5, sizeImg.height + 5);  

JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("AIRLINE");
imgPanel.add(lbl2)

sizeImg = lbl2.getPreferredSize();
lbl2.setBounds(100 + imgPanelInsets.left, 5 + imgPanelInsets.top,
             sizeImg.width + 5, sizeImg.height + 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GridLayout` on your `imgPanel` and add the labels using a loop. Make sure to center the label text using `SwingConstants.CENTER`.

The labels will all be equidistant apart and you do not need to set any insets or margins.

```
List<String> labels = Arrays.asList("STD", "AIRLINE", "DESTINATION", "FLIGHT", "GATE", "STATUS");
imgPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, labels.size())); // 1 row, 6 columns
labels.stream().forEach(s -> {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(s, SwingConstants.CENTER); // centered label text
    label.setFont(new Font("Century Gothic", Font.BOLD, 28));
    label.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    imgPanel.add(label);
});
```

---

You could also just set the layout before you start adding your labels, but this is more cumbersome and not dynamic.

```
imgPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 6)); // Six labels tiled horizontally
```

And do not forget to center your label text.

```
schedHd = new JLabel("STD", SwingConstants.CENTER);
airlineHd = new JLabel("AIRLINE", SwingConstants.CENTER);
// etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the gridlayout but it wasn't working. The labels are not meant to have equal space between them so I decided to follow the answer I gave above. Thanks once for your assistance.